# functions in same class

Tags: ollydbg

is there a way in ollydbg that allows me to find all functions in a class , like if I know one function of that class can I find the other functions , so like

```
class A{

int sum();
int powr();
}
```

and in ollydbg I know where to break on`sum()` but I don't know where to break on `power()`, is there any way that allows me to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is the functions are non-virtual, then there is no general way to determine from the binary whether they belong to the same class or not. Non-virtual functions (like in the example you provided) are statically linked at compile time and in the resulting executable, they appear as a simple call to the function. There is even no simple and solid way to know which class such a function belongs to.

However in practice, linkers very ofter put functions from one class close to each other. Sometimes even in the same order as they were defined. But this is not guaranteed and there are many cases where this is not true.

If you are talking about *virtual* functions, then this is a completely different story, since pointers to virtual functions must be stored in a structure called "virtual method table". This structure must be defined (one for each class) somewhere in the binary and if you can locate it, then you get a list of virtual methods and their pointers.